# Report Viewer "filter"

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Can you filter the results of the Report Viewer according to a name of a column with the value designated by a string? For example, just show data saved from the database of the "User" column with the value "RAFA", designated by a string in the Report Viewer form. Visual Studio 2017

Comment: You would just use that in your query that populates the report. "select [data saved] from [your table] where [user] = 'RAFA'

Comment: Where exactly do I add this?

Comment: In your sql query.